# Capturar todos os telefones de um arquivo de texto

Tags: php, regex

Possuo um log registros em html, e gostaria de capturar todos os números de telefone, tanto fixos como móveis que estão espalhados pelo arquivo, uso a seguinte expressão regular atualmente: `/(\(?\d{2}\)?) ?9?\d{4}-?\d{4}/`, só que ela está deixando passar alguns números que não são telefones, o que está errado?

```
preg_match_all('/(\(?\d{2}\)?) ?9?\d{4}-?\d{4}/', $phone, $out);

echo '<pre/>';
print_r(array_shift($out));
```

número que passou: `99988877766`

Comment: Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar exemplos de quais seriam estes números que estão sendo capturados mas que não são telefones?

Comment: mostre um trecho desse arquivo. Sem isso é inviável

Comment: por exemplo, CPFs sem traços estão passando.

Comment: Coloque um exemplo do seu arquivo, cite todos os formatos que existem no arquivo de numero de telefone. Não entendi seu comentário sobre CPF, sendo que esta querendo capturar Numero de Telefone.

Answer (score 1):

### Depende do padrão de números

Um exemplo de expressão regular:

```
/(?:\((\d{2})\))?\s?(\d{3,5}[-\s]?\d{4})/
```

Ela vai capturar, no grupo 1 o DDD e no grupo 2 o número, incluindo traços ou espaços.

Padrões que ela captura:

```
(11)1234-0000
11-123-4567
11-1234567
(11)1234-1234
(11)123-1203
(11)12349-0293
1234-2039
99888-9292
```

Para ter mais acertos na captura você deve antes buscar todas as possibilidades de formatos que você tem no seu arquivo. Por exemplo, essa expressão não captura números que tenham o código de discagem internacional.

Para testar as expressões você pode usar o [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/). Ele permite fazer os testes de forma online.